Why are there a large number of integer constants in the generated assembly code for std::print?
I was playing around with a "hello world!" program using the new std::print function on clang 18.1.0, and I noticed a couple thousand lines of integer constants, as shown here on godbolt. What purpose do they serve, and why are they not present in a classic std::cout -based "hello world!"?

Various unicode tables such as the extended_grapheme_cluster_table

@Jester plus I guess at .LJTI17_0 and onwards there are some branch tables.

You mean the blocks like this?
.LJTI17_0:
    .long   .LBB17_1-.LJTI17_0
    .long   .LBB17_2-.LJTI17_0
    .long   .LBB17_24-.LJTI17_0

Those are tables of 32-bit offsets from the table to other labels, probably for switch in position-independent code.  The JTI part of the label name presumably stands for Jump Table, the I maybe for Indirect?
I see in parser<char> there's code that uses it like GCC Jump Table initialization code generating movsxd and add?:
    lea     rdx, [rip + .LJTI29_0]
    movsxd  rcx, dword ptr [rdx + 4*rcx]   # sign-extending load indexing into the table
    add     rcx, rdx                       # add it to the table address
    jmp     rcx                            # to get a jump target

Godbolt by default filters code for library functions, so that code is hidden, but std::print is defined in the header so it compiles into a significant amount of code for the compilation unit that uses it. Unlike <iostream> where operator<<'s definition is only in the library, not available for inlining, so the asm in the caller is just a constructor call for globals like std::cout, and just a normal function call.
I also see a few tables of literal integer constants like
std::__1::__extended_grapheme_custer_property_boundary::__entries:
        .long   145
        .long   20485
        .long   22545
        .long   26624
        .long   28945
        .long   260609
        .long   346115
        .long   354305
        .long   356355
        .long   1574642
     ...

std::__1::__width_estimation_table::__entries:
        .long   71303263
        .long   147226625
        .long   147472385
        .long   150618115
        .long   150732800

Their names seem fairly self-explanatory, or at least long enough to search the source for the code that defines and uses them.
Also a table of powers of 10 that fit in 32 bits, with a name that indicates the purpose:
std::__1::__itoa::__pow10_32:
        .long   0
        .long   10
        .long   100
        .long   1000
        .long   10000
        .long   100000
        .long   1000000
        .long   10000000
        .long   100000000
        .long   1000000000

Binary or linear search of a small table can be faster than actually multiplying x *= 10 to get a value to compare against to see the decimal-digit length of a number, especially if used repeatedly.  And that's something that you might want to do so you can store digits into the itoa output buffer as you generate them LSD-first for non-power-of-2 bases and still have the first digit at a known position. (Otherwise you could just start at the end of a buffer and copy, but that would have a store-forwarding stall if you do a wide copy, and you might not know it's safe to write past the end of an odd length.  See How do I print an integer in Assembly Level Programming without printf from the c library? (itoa, integer to decimal ASCII string))
